# Two polylines could form a convex quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

A close polyline $\Delta$ with length $n$ here means a sequence of segments $A_1A_2,\ldots, A_{n-1}A_n$ and $A_nA_1$ so that there are no two segments $A_iA_{i+1}$ and $A_jA_{j+1}$, with $1\leq i,j\leq n$ and $i\neq j$ such that the segments $A_iA_{i+1}$ intersect $A_jA_{j+1}$.

Let $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$ be two close polylines, with length 2016,  such that any three lines which contains segments of $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$ are not concurent. The problem state that we always find two segment $AB$, $CD$ where $AB\in \Delta_1$ and $CD\in \Delta_2$ so that $A,B,C,D$ form a convex quadrilateral.

I could prove the question in case $\Delta_1\cap \Delta_2 \neq \emptyset$. But I have no idea for the rest cases.

Comment: When you say "any three lines which contains segments of ... are not concurent" you mean that these lines are the support lines of the segments and that they are not concurrent  IN THE SAME POINT, is that right ?

Comment: Yes I mean that, sorry for bad English!